# Is it possible to turn WoW PC client to a Mac one?

Tags: pc, world-of-warcraft, macos

I have a World of Warcraft client downloaded, a PC version.

Could I perhaps by replacing some files turn it into a Mac version? I just want to save my time not downloading another 10+ Gb for Mac — I'm pretty sure resource files and stuff are the same for both OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't move the WoW Folder from Mac to PC and make it run, sadly. Native programs are compiled different for Mac and PC and World of Warcraft is no exception.

However, you can move the Interface and WTF folders to keep your interface and Add-On configuration intact.

Reference can be found [here.](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/2721564125)

Comment: What about the data folder? These files aren't executable and also make up the vast bulk of the data that needs downloading.

Comment: @soulstriderx, I do know that apps for Mac and PC are different, thanks :) I'm asking about a quick convertion, like adding appropriate *.app folder. I'm just pretty sure all the big fat data, i.e textures, texture maps, sounds and stuff are the same for each platform. Anyway, seems that link provided have some useful info, thank you!

Comment: The reference you gave states clearly that it is OK to move the Data folder, which will save you most of the download; only a small bit of Mac-specific information will have to be downloaded after that.

Answer (score 2):

so, let's say I come up with a list of files that you want to replace with Mac versions, the next question would be "Where are you going to get those files?" If you have access to a Mac with those files, you can copy over the entire WoW folder. Problem solved. Much easier than you mention.

But let's try answering it anyway:

So, .exe and .dll files will have to be replaced. Those are going to be written exclusively for the Windows Environment (Win32 api calls...), so you can't save them. MPQ files are Blizzard data files, and those can be saved. Looking at the other files I have in my WoW install folder there's a bunch of other files you don't need, like patch and downloader files...

There's a few other extensions that are just data files:

- .db
- .mfil
- .pfil
- .tfil

I also have a manifest file. That's microsoft specific, but it's also a data file. It should be associated with .dll files, so it doesn't need to be copied.

According to the blue poster on this thread:

http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/2723296541

There's a bunch of folders you can just delete, because they'll get built automatically by the system. Those are the files that you can keep and copy over if you want, because they're just data files, but they also aren't strictly necessary to have WoW work. What is it you're optimizing for?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is not entirely right…

I have done this. I had a gaming PC and wanted to play WoW in my Mac work laptop when I'm traveling.

Here are the steps:

1. Download and install game client from the battle.net account page, eg: https://us.battle.net/account/management/download/
2. Once the first part of the install has completed, it’ll load the launcher and start downloading a huge amount of data files. Quit the installer.
3. Copy the “Data” and “Updates” folders from your PC WoW install into your Mac’s Wow install folder.
4. Run the “World of Warcraft Repair” app on the Mac. It’ll think for a while and should finish with a “Repair successful”
5. Run the “World of Warcraft Launcher” app on the Mac. It will download the latest patch executable.

At this point World of Warcraft should be fully patched, with all content downloaded. Log in and enjoy!

Remember to eat in real life too! ;)

(p.s.: I've done this and it works)

(source: http://daniel.ivydra.com/post/2382835945/copying-world-of-warcraft-install-from-pc-to-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

Yea, It is possible. After transferring your PC WoW to a Mac, you only need to download the WoW.app that is like the WoW.exe for Windows.